# Run Junit Test on a dynamically loaded class

Tags: dynamic, reflection, junit

I have to get the source code of a class, compile it and then execute a Junit test on it. I managed in many ways to compile dynamically my code, generating a .class file, so that's not the problem.

Since this procedure is done dynamically, how can I invoke methods and constructors of this class in the JUnit test case without using Java reflection?

Comment: Could you give some concrete examples? You say: you generate source code, compile that, and then you want to run unit tests on the compiled output? Couldn't you then generate unit tests as well? Otherwise, reflection would be the only option that comes to my mind.

Comment: @GhostCat I managed to achieve that pre-compiling the test, putting it into the same directory of the compiled class (done on the fly) and then running it from the code. (I had some troubles compiling the test on the fly but i did it). This way i avoided the reflection use because i can write Unit Test with the lowest coupling possible.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are saying; but it sounds like you found your solution then.